# PHPUnit RuntimeException: Instances of Aws\S3\S3Client cannot be serialized

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cakephp, amazon-s3, phpunit

Installed Burzum's CakePHP File Storage plugin in my CakePHP application, and with it the Amazon AWS PHP SDK. Now all my 515 unit tests fail with the following message:

```
$ php vendor/bin/phpunit --filter testGenerateWithOnlyUppercase
PHPUnit 5.7.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 273 ms, Memory: 26.25MB

There was 1 error:

1) App\Test\TestCase\Auth\DefaultPasswordGeneratorTest::testGenerateWithOnlyUppercase
RuntimeException: Instances of Aws\S3\S3Client cannot be serialized

/var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php:230

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

(In the above example I run only one test, but it fails on each and every test, whether I use PHPUnit --filter or not, each time with the same error)

CakePHP version is 3.4.7, PHPUnit version is 5.7.0. To be honest I have no idea why PHPUnit is getting into the AWS sdk for each and every test, and why it's failing like this. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**update:**

Following ndm's tip I've put `echo \Cake\Error\Debugger::trace();` just before `AwsClient.php:230`. The output is:

```
Aws\AwsClient::__sleep() - ROOT/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php, line 230
serialize - [internal], line ??
SebastianBergmann\GlobalState\Snapshot::snapshotGlobals() - ROOT/vendor/sebastian/global-state/src/Snapshot.php, line 313
SebastianBergmann\GlobalState\Snapshot::__construct() - ROOT/vendor/sebastian/global-state/src/Snapshot.php, line 121
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::createGlobalStateSnapshot() - ROOT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php, line 2488
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::snapshotGlobalState() - ROOT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php, line 2407
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::runBare() - ROOT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php, line 928
PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult::run() - ROOT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php, line 701
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::run() - ROOT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php, line 909
PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::run() - ROOT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php, line 728
PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::run() - ROOT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php, line 728
PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::run() - ROOT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php, line 728
PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner::doRun() - ROOT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php, line 487
PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::run() - ROOT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php, line 188
PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() - ROOT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php, line 118
[main] - ROOT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit, line 52
```

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! Also ideally show/describe the proper context, ie show/highlight the code that actually triggers the error.

Comment: Thanks. There is not much more unfortunately but I edited my post with the complete output of PHPUnit. I don't know what code actually triggers the error.

Comment: I think I've had a similar problem before, but I don't remember what it fixed it. However, the problem is pretty clear: Something (thats the part you need to figure out) is trying to serialize an instance of an object that is not serializeable. I recommend you to mock the adapter any way or mock the storage related methods in your tests.

Comment: Hi mr.Burzum! The weird thing is that this error pops up on all my unit tests, even those that don't touch amazon or any file storage at all. There must be something basic that I'm missing.

Comment: If you don't get a stacktrace (not even in the logs), then use a proper debugger like XDebug and set and inspect a breakpoint on `AwsClient.php:230`, or manually add debug info to the code, like emitting `\Cake\Error\Debugger::trace()` from before that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that an instance of `Aws\S3\S3Client` is set as a global variable. PHPUnit then tries to serialize this, and fails. The solution was to set `backupGlobals` to false in the `phpunit.xml` configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    colors="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    syntaxCheck="false"
    bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php"
    backupGlobals="false"
    >
    <php>
        <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
        <ini name="apc.enable_cli" value="1"/>
    </php>

    <!-- Add any additional test suites you want to run here -->
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
...
```

Shout-out to ndm and burzum for pointing me in the right direction.